# onClick(CoroutineContext) Unit is deprecated Kotlin Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, anko

I have migrated my project to Kotlin 1.3 and then it is showing this

[image: Deprecated OnClick warning]

Was that means we have to use the again the **long and old fashioned setOnClickListener** method or they have introduced some another method. And why they are dropping it?

Comment: Where do you get `onClick()` from?

Comment: @tynn from Anko Kotlin Library

Comment: Coroutines were made stable in 1.3 IIRC. That could be the source

Answer (score 0):

> The 0.10.7 release has two satellites 0.10.7-eap13 and 0.10.7-rc13
>   which are meant to be used with Kotlin 1.3 and release
>   kotlinx.coroutines. Feel free to try them and provide any feedback.

[Github/Kotlin/Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)

I just tried "0.10.7-rc13" instead of "0.10.7" and it's working for now. You also have to update imports from "sdk25" to "sdk27".

Comment: I am using 0.10.6 for anko and also importing the sdk27 @dmitrijkiltau